# JQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded from bootstrap.datepicker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a well-runing good code before, my guess is in datepicker..it started to show that error when i played around and testing clicking on datepicker.

I know that exceeding stack size meaning that I have some kind of infinite recursive of-never-returning-back-to-the-base or whatsoever, can you show me how to fix this?

I mean, the error is quite random, sometimes when you change the date it's okay, sometimes it just stopped. it's not always crashing when you change date on the datepicker.

I never get the error on other place other than datepicker section (start and end date) and before I make the datepicker it was okay.

here's the screenshot of error message on console rooted from [jquery.min.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJign.png)
and [bootstrap.datepicker.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhIW3.png)

The HTML-counterpart (HTML and JS is separated) is just [basic form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc1HM.png)

Here's my JS code

```
$F.loadView(function() {

"use strict";
return {
   title: 'Master Discount - HelloBill',
   viewtitle: 'Master Discount',
   urlController: 'discount/',
   urlControllerHardware: 'hardware/',
   urlControllerLicense: 'license/',
    afterLoad: function(param) {
        var self = this;
        var th = this.parent;
        var post = '';
        var txt = 'inserted';

  //bwt munculin judul
        if (param.param[0]) {
            $('#topic').text('Update ' + self.viewtitle);
            txt = 'updated';
            getUpdateData(param, self, txt);
            post = param.param[0];
            $('#judul_detail').removeClass("looptemplate");
        } else {
            $('#topic').text('Add ' + self.viewtitle);
        }

  //mengeluarkan detail barang2 yg akan didiskon
        $('#Type').change(function(){
          if($('#Type').val()){
            $('#judul_detail').removeClass("looptemplate");
            if($('#Type').val() == 'Hardware') {
              // self.refreshTableTes(9, "Hardware");
              self.refreshTableHardware(param, self, txt);
            }
            else {
              // self.refreshTableTes(12, "License");
              self.refreshTableLicense(param, self, txt);
            }
          } else {
            $('#judul_detail').addClass("looptemplate");
            $('#Body').empty();
          }
        });

  //Datepicker
        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
          var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
          dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
          return dat;
        }
        Date.prototype.reFormat = function() {
          var twoDigitMonth = ((this.getMonth()+1) < 10) ? '0'+(this.getMonth()+1) : (this.getMonth()+1);
          var currentDate = this.getFullYear() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + this.getDate();
          return currentDate;
        }

        var fullDate1 = new Date();
        var dumDate1 = '';
        $('#StartDate').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          autoclose: false,
          startDate: fullDate1.reFormat()
          // beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday
        }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
          var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
          $('#EndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
          // alert(dumDate1);
          // alert($('#EndDate').val());
          if(startDate > dumDate1 || $('#EndDate').val() == '') {
            // $('#EndDate').val($(this).val());
            $('#EndDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
          }
          dumDate1 = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        });
        var fullDate2 = new Date();
        var dumDate2 = '';
        $('#EndDate').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          autoclose: false,
          startDate: fullDate2.reFormat()
          // beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday
        }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
          var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
          if(startDate < dumDate2 || $('#StartDate').val() == '') {
            $('#EndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
            $('#StartDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
            // $('#EndDate.day').css('background-color', 'coral');
          }
          dumDate2 = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        });


  //Discount Percentage or Value
        $('input.terikat').keyup(function(){
          if($(this).val()) {
            $('input.terikat').not(this).val('');
          }
        });

        var numbersOnly = document.getElementsByClassName('numbers-only');
        for(var i = 0 ; i < numbersOnly.length ; i++) {
          numbersOnly[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            var key   = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

            if (!( [8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
                 (key == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey  ) ) ||
                 (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                 (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
                 (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
               )) e.preventDefault();
         });
       }

  //Discount Start Date and End Date
        var dur = document.getElementById("StartDate");
        var dur2 = document.getElementById("EndDate");
        var checkboxDuration = document.getElementById("duration");

        dur.disabled = true;
        dur2.disabled = true;
        dur.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";
        dur2.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";

        $("#duration").click(function(){
          if(checkboxDuration.checked){
            dur.disabled = false;
            dur2.disabled = false;
            dur.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            dur2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
          } else {
            dur.disabled = true;
            dur2.disabled = true;
            dur.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";
            dur2.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";
          }
        });

  //Mengatur checkbox yang select all
        $('#select_all').click(function(){
          if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $(".selectedItem").prop("checked", true);
          }
          else{
            $(".selectedItem").prop("checked", false);
          }
        });


  //Submit Form
        $('#action').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();

            var ser = $F.serialize('#action');
            console.log(ser);

        //insert ke tabel diskon dan detail diskon
              $F.service({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: 'discount/action',
                  data: JSON.stringify(ser),
                  success: function(data){
                    if(data != null) {
                      if(data.Status == 0) {
                          $F.popup.show({
                              content: data.Message
                          });
                          $('.modal-content').attr("style", "width : 250px");
                          setTimeout(function() {
                              window.location = $F.config.get('baseUri') + '#/master/discount';
                              $('.popup-close-button').click();
                          }, 1500);
                      } else {
                        var err = '';
                        for (var field in data.Errors) {
                            err += data.Errors[field].ID + ' : ' + data.Errors[field].Message + '</br>';
                        }
                      }
                    } else {
                          DZ.showAlertWarning("Something is wrong, no data is " + txt, "#error_insert_update", 0);
                      }
                  }
              }); //tutup service (insert diskon dan detail diskon)

          });
        }, refreshTableHardware: function (param, self, jenis) {
          $F.service({
              url:self.urlControllerHardware+"getAllData",
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(data){
                if(data != null) {
                  var x = data.length;
                  var body = $("#Body");
                  var depan = '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div><div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">';
                  var belakang = '</div></div>';
                  body.empty();

                  for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
                    var temp = depan + '<input type="checkbox" class="selectedItem" name="Item[]" id="detail-'+i+'" value="' + data[i].HardwareID + '"> <label for="detail-'+i+'">' + data[i].HardwareName + '</label>' + belakang;
                    body.append(temp);
                  }
                  if(jenis == 'updated') {getDetailData(param, self);}
                } else {
                  DZ.showAlertWarning("Cannot fetch the data, no services is available for now", "#Body", 0);
                }
              }
          })
        }, refreshTableLicense: function (param, self, jenis) {
          $F.service({
              url:self.urlControllerLicense+"getAllData",
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(data){
                if(data != null) {
                  var x = data.length;
                  var body = $("#Body");
                  var depan = '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div><div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">';
                  var belakang = '</div></div>';
                  body.empty();

                  for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
                    var temp = depan + '<input type="checkbox" class="selectedItem" name="Item[]" id="detail-'+i+'" value="' + data[i].LicenseID + '"> <label for="detail-'+i+'">' + data[i].LicenseName + '</label>' + belakang;
                    body.append(temp);
                  }
                  if(jenis == 'updated') getDetailData(param, self);
                } else {
                  DZ.showAlertWarning("Cannot fetch the data, no services is available for now", "#Body", 0);
                }
              }
          })
        }

      };

function NotBeforeToday(date)
{
    var now = new Date();//this gets the current date and time
    if (date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() > now.getDate())
        return [true];
    if (date.getFullYear() >= now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() > now.getMonth())
       return [true];
     if (date.getFullYear() > now.getFullYear())
       return [true];
    return [false];
}

function getUpdateData(param, self, jenis) {
    $F.service({
        type: 'get',
        url: self.urlController + 'getUpdateData/' + param.param[0],
        success: function(data) {
          if(data != null) {
            var item = data.Discount[0];
            $('#DiscountID').val(item.DiscountID);
            $('#DiscountCode').val(item.DiscountCode);
            $('#DiscountName').val(item.DiscountName);
            $('#Description').val(item.Description);
            $('#Type').val(item.Type);
            if(item.Type == 'Hardware') self.refreshTableHardware(param, self, jenis);
            else self.refreshTableLicense(param, self, jenis);
            // getDetailData(param, self);
            $('#Percentage').val(item.DiscountPercentage);
            $('#Value').val(item.DiscountValue);
            if(item.StartDate && item.EndDate) {
              // alert(item.StartDate);
              // alert(item.EndDate);
              $('#duration').prop("checked", true);
              $('#StartDate').prop("disabled", false);
              $('#StartDate').css("background-color", "white");
              $('#EndDate').prop("disabled", false);
              $('#EndDate').css("background-color", "white");
              var i = item.StartDate;
              var j = item.EndDate;
              // $('#Period').val(i + ' - ' + j);
              $('#StartDate').val(i);
              $('#EndDate').val(j);
            }
          } else {
            DZ.showAlertWarning("Cannot fetch the data, no services is available for now", "#error", 0);
          }
        }
    });
}

function getDetailData(param, self) {
    $F.service({
        type: 'get',
        url: self.urlController + 'getDetailData/' + param.param[0],
        success: function(data) {
          if(data != null) {
            var x = data.Discount.length;
            var select = $('.selectedItem');

            for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
              var discount = data.Discount[i];
              var item='';
              if(discount.HardwareID) {
                item = discount.HardwareID;
              } else {
                item = discount.LicenseID;
              }
              // alert(item);

              select.each(function(){
                // alert($(this).val());
                if($(this).val() == item) {
                  // alert(item);
                  $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                }
                // else alert(item);
              });
            }
          } else {
            DZ.showAlertWarning("Cannot fetch the data, no services is available for now", "#Body", 0);
          }
        }
    });
}
}());
```

Here's the snippet I prepare, I reduce some of the code but retain the main feature (including the datepicker itself).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Datepicker
  Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
  }
  Date.prototype.reFormat = function() {
    var twoDigitMonth = ((this.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' + (this.getMonth() + 1) : (this.getMonth() + 1);
    var currentDate = this.getFullYear() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + this.getDate();
    return currentDate;
  }

  var fullDate1 = new Date();
  var dumDate1 = '';
  $('#StartDate').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: false,
    startDate: fullDate1.reFormat()
    // beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#EndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    // alert(dumDate1);
    // alert($('#EndDate').val());
    if (startDate > dumDate1 || $('#EndDate').val() == '') {
      // $('#EndDate').val($(this).val());
      $('#EndDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
    }
    dumDate1 = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  });
  var fullDate2 = new Date();
  var dumDate2 = '';
  $('#EndDate').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: false,
    startDate: fullDate2.reFormat()
    // beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    if (startDate < dumDate2 || $('#StartDate').val() == '') {
      $('#EndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
      $('#StartDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
      // $('#EndDate.day').css('background-color', 'coral');
    }
    dumDate2 = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  });

  //Discount Start Date and End Date
  var dur = document.getElementById("StartDate");
  var dur2 = document.getElementById("EndDate");
  var checkboxDuration = document.getElementById("duration");

  dur.disabled = true;
  dur2.disabled = true;
  dur.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";
  dur2.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";

  $("#duration").click(function() {
    if (checkboxDuration.checked) {
      dur.disabled = false;
      dur2.disabled = false;
      dur.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      dur2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      // $("#Period").css("border-color", "Aqua");
    } else {
      dur.disabled = true;
      dur2.disabled = true;
      dur.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";
      dur2.style.backgroundColor = "Gainsboro";
      // $("#Period").css("border-color", "coral");
    }
  });


  //Discount Percentage or Value
  $('input.terikat').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $('input.terikat').not(this).val('');
    }
  });

  var numbersOnly = document.getElementsByClassName('numbers-only');
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersOnly.length; i++) {
    numbersOnly[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

      if (!([8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
          (key == 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
          (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
          (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
          (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
        )) e.preventDefault();
    });
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function minmax(value, min, max) {
    if (parseInt(value) < min)
      return 0;
    else if (parseInt(value) > max)
      return 100;
    else return value;
  }
</script>


<h5 class="panel-title text-center title-content" id="topic"></h5>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="action" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="DiscountID" name="DiscountID" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="DiscountCode" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Discount Code</label>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DiscountCode" name="DiscountCode">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="DiscountName" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Discount Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DiscountName" name="DiscountName">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Description" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Discount Info</label>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="Description" name="Description" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 text-center">Discount is calculated by</div>

      <label for="persen" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">
              <!-- <input type="radio" id="persen" checked>  -->
              Percentage
            </label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 100)" class="form-control numbers-only terikat" id="Percentage" name="Percentage">
      </div>

      <label for="value" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">
              <!-- <input type="radio" id="value">  -->
              Value
            </label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control numbers-only terikat" id="Value" name="Value">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
      <label for="duration" class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" id="duration"> Discount has limited duration
          </label>
      <label for="Period" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Period</label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-prepend input-group">
          <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control dur" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" readonly="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <!-- <div class="input-prepend input-group"> -->
        <!-- <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control dur" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" readonly="">
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Type" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Discount Type</label>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <select class="form-control" id="Type" name="Type">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please select</option>
          <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
          <option value="License">License</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group looptemplate" id="judul_detail">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div>
      <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
             Select the item(s) whose discount will applied to:
          </label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-right">
        <input type="checkbox" class="control-label" id="select_all">
        <label for="select_all">Select All</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Body"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div id="error_insert_update"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save Change
        </button>
    <a type="button" href="#/master/discount" class="btn btn-success btn-addon m-b-sm">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually due to the change in Bootstrap 3 in the box-sizing to border-box. However, the problem is a from a couple of things:
1. Our height/width methods are subtracting the border width from the box, even though box-sizing is set to border-box.
2. The autosize module is doing a get/set from inside of an after listener. This wasn't breaking before because it was always setting maxHeight to the same value, so it never called the after listener

The fix, of course, is the one I sent up (which is to not fire the _syncHeight method if event.src == 'ui'), but we should also look into fixing our width/height methods as well to account for border-box being set.

Comment: uh uh, i knew it..seems hard to understand by me. btw, where's the fix you sent? i mean , i'm new here...